# Rule should not fire when user logs in with one-time-link from password recovery

Tags: 7, users, rules

I have a rule for user-login that redirects them to their content area and shows a welcome message with some instructions. But when a user uses the password recovery mechanism that rule should not fire. I have tried "path has URL alias" and "user/reset/*" as value. But it did not work. I can't figure out what else i could use.

Reason is: users need their current password, which they don't know, when they are going manually to their user/n/edit page. When the rule wouldn't fire they'd be redirected to the correct password reset page without the current password requirement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to give this a try:

- Rules Event: User has logged in.
- Rules Condition: Text Comparison with

  - Text Data Selector = `site:current-page:path`
  - Matching Text = `reset`
  - Comparison Operator = `contains`
- Rules Action(s): whatever makes sense.

I'm not 100% sure about the value of the "Matching Text" (if it's not `reset`, then adapt that value to something that fits for these kinds of one time login URLs).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm. Rules is so powerful, but one needs to get used to it, especially if it's not used on a daily basis.

Comment: @Volker Merci for accept and +1 ... I fully agree with your comment (there are not many business logic cases where I can't get it done using some kind of custom rule). Just in case you do want to get used to it, and whenever you have time: have a look at some (or all?) of [these answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a39516%20%5brules%5d) ... Then ask yourself "so what is it that you cannot do with Rules?" ...